# 'Meta' object has no attribute 'object_name'

Tags: django, django-admin

При вхождении в админку Django 1.6.3, ввожу логин и пароль superuser'а и получаю такое сообщение:

```
AttributeError at /admin/

'Meta' object has no attribute 'object_name'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version:     1.6.3
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'Meta' object has no attribute 'object_name'

Exception Location:     /home/Project/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py in index, line 353
Python Executable:  /home/Project/myvenv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.9
Python Path:    

['/home/Project/mysite/mysite',
 '/home/Project/mysite',
 '/home/Project/myvenv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/Project/myvenv/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/Project/myvenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/Project/myvenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/Project/myvenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/Project/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/Project/myvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в классе `Config` и дочерним классе  `Meta` отсутствует переменная `object_name` со значением `Config`. Можно использовать последнюю версию `django-constance-updated` или исправить вручную.

Вручную будет выглядеть так:

Запускаем файл по адресу: `Lib/site-packages/constance/admin.py`

И добавляем переменную в классе:

```
class Config(object):
    class Meta(object):
        [здесь могут быть другие переменные]
        object_name = 'Config' # вставляем эту строку
```

Сохраняем файл и перезагружаем сервер.

Источник https://github.com/jazzband/django-constance/issues/69